# On iPad - raphael elements mouseover, mouseup, mouseout events are not working

Tags: svg, raphael, mouseover, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-events

I have set mouseover, mouseup, mouseout events on rapahel element, which listens to the jquery drag (elements which is dragged using jquery draggable).

```
this.elem.mouseover(this.handleMouseOver );
this.elem.mouseout( this.handleMouseOut );
this.elem.mouseup( this.handleMouseUpOver );

handleMouseOver : function(e) {
},
....
```

and similarly for other two handlers.

It works fine on desktop browsers, though none of the above events seems to be kick-in when I am dragging text on the raphael element on ipad/iphone.

Is there any setting, or custom code needs to be added in order to make it work?

Update -
I tried to attach `touchstart` and `touchend` events, but if I am in middle of drag event, those are not getting fired.

Comment: Wondering if you need touchevents on an ipad ?

Comment: I tried to bind touchstart and touchend, however because the drag event is already in action its not detecting that on the raphael element.

Comment: http://touchpunch.furf.com/ will fix this issue

Comment: @AlvinK. I am already using it for the drag element, and its working fine for the dragging the non-raphael element. The issue is on the raphael element where its not able to detect the drop event on it. I tried adding touchstart, touchend on the raphael element, but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for Raphael, implement your own drag with: `Element.drag(move, start, up)` (ref: [Element.drag](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.drag)). Reason being jQuery UI drag event is not stable with Raphael DOM (from my own experience).

1. `move = ...` - update the Rapheal Element `(x,y)` position
2. `start = ...` - outline the Rapheal Element (checks if Element is already active)
3. `up = ...` - remove outline of Raphael Element (optional: detach listener)

Note: IOS touch triggers **TWO** `mousedown()`, hence #2 checks to avoid this (not sure if IOS 8 does this too)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are suggesting to use raphael element for the one which I am dragging. Currently its HTML element and I drag over the raphael element. Lets say I use the raphael element to drag and place it over the another raphael element, how would I detect that over which element the drop event is been called.

Comment: Raphael handles all that too. Quote: "...When element will be dragged over another element `drag.over.<id>` will be fired as well".